# D3 Treemap headers

Tags: javascript, d3.js, header, treemap

I'm trying to add headers at the top of each rectangle which have the name of the parent in them. I'm trying to follow this example https://bl.ocks.org/deenar/336efdeb97f1c79d4a6b but honestly don't properly understand it as I'm still new to D3.

Currently I've added the following to add a header but doesn't seem to show anything:

```
var header = nodes.filter(function(d) {
    return !d.children;
    }); 

var headerCells = svg.selectAll("g.cell.header")
    .data(header, function(d) { console.log("gf"+name);
        return d.name;
        });

var headerEnterTransition = headerCells.enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "cell header")
        .on("click", function(d) {
            zoom(d);
        });
headerEnterTransition.append("rect")
.attr("width", function(d) {
    return Math.max(0.01, d.dx);
})  
.attr("height", headerHeight)
        .style("fill", "red");
    headerEnterTransition.append('foreignObject')
        .attr("class", "foreignObject")
        .append("xhtml:body")
        .attr("class", "labelbody")
        .append("div")
        .attr("class", "label");
```

I can get a rectangle header to show if i change:

```
var header = nodes.filter(function(d) {
        return d.children;
        });
```

To:

```
var header = nodes.filter(function(d) {
        return !d.children;
        });
```

But this results in the treemap chart disappearing and a clickable rectangle which then expands once clicked on. Full code could be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/noobiecode/9ev9qjt3/33/

I'm hoping i haven't confused anyone as i do have a tendency of doing so. In any case, here's what i'm trying to achieve:

[image]

I'm at the point where i'm completely puzzled and was hoping if someone should shed some light on this matter.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you just want to change the position of text from middle to top and have zoom functionality on click of text?
Have a look here: https://jsfiddle.net/q16m6wey/

```
    parentCell.append("svg:text")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return d.dx / 2;
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return 10;
  })
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.parent.name;
  })
.style('cursor', 'pointer')
  .style("opacity", function(d) {
    console.log(this.getComputedTextLength());
    d.w = this.getComputedTextLength();
    return d.dx > d.w ? 1 : 0;
  })
.on("click", function(d) {
    console.log(d.parent);
    return zoom(node == d.parent ? root : d.parent);
  });
```

Comment: I want the name of the parent(text) at the top once like this example https://bl.ocks.org/deenar/336efdeb97f1c79d4a6b. Many thanks for helping.